# On page load, fading in and out one div after another with jQuery

Tags: jquery, web, jquery-animate, fadein, fadeout

I am working on a piece of my personal website and what I want to do is a simple animation.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="wrapper">--- Main website body ---</div>
<div class="intro1">
    <div class="name1">John</div>
    <div class="name2">Doe</div>
</div>
<div class="intro2">
    <div class="prof1">Designer</div>
    <div class="prof2">Developer</div>
</div>​


<style>
    body {background: rgba(0,0,0,1); margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgba(255,255,255,1); }
    .wrapper {width:100%; height:100%; max-height: 100%; background: rgba(0,0,0,1); display: none;}
    .intro1 {width: 500px; height: 150px; margin: 40% auto 0% auto; padding: 0px; display: none;}
    .intro2 {width: 500px; height: 150px; margin: 40% auto 0% auto; padding: 0px; display: none;}
</style>


$(function() {
    $('.intro1').fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000);
    $(function() {
        $('.intro2').fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000);
    });
});​
```

Here is the break down of what should happen:

1. Page loads with simple black background
2. Div (.intro1) slowly fades in with possible sliding in from the top and going downwards
3. Div (.intro1) slowly fades out with possible sliding out downwards followed by removing the element completely
4. Div (.intro2) slowly fades in with possible sliding in from the top and going downwards
5. Div (.intro2) slowly fades out with possible sliding out downwards followed by removing the element completely
6. Div (.wrapper) slowly fades in

This is what I have so far and I am nor sure what I need to do next.

Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/gVp7m/

Comment: You should use a callback function, as a parameter for `fadeOut`.

Comment: dont forget to give helpful ppls upticks and check an answer that fits! :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.intro1').fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000, function(){
       $('.intro2').fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000);
    });
});​
```

Comment: O! That worked great.
After .intro2 fade outs, do I just do the same for .wrapper ?

Comment: Like this:

`$(function() {
    $('.intro1').fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('.intro2').fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $('.wrapper').fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
});​`

Comment: That works great, I sincerely appreciate the help. Is it possible to make the elements slide in while fading in?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it for example.
It looks more complex than it actually is

```
$(function() {
    function showIntro(nr){
        $('.intro'+nr).css({
            'margin-top':'20%',
            'display':'block',
            'opacity':0})
            .animate({
                'margin-top':'40%',
                'opacity':1},2000,function(){

                $(this).delay(1000).animate({
                    'margin-top':'60%',
                    'opacity':0},2000,function(){

                        $(this).remove();
                        if(nr==1){
                            showIntro(2);
                        }else if(nr==2){
                            $('.wrapper').fadeIn(2000);
                        }
                });          
        });
    };

    showIntro(1);
});​
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/gVp7m/4/

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use the callback function to trigger the next animation after the first one completes :)

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/gVp7m/2/)

```
$(function() {

$('.intro1').fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000, function() {

    $('.intro2').fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000, function() {

        $('.wrapper').fadeIn(1000);

    });

});
```

});

Comment: That looks awesome, thank you! Is it possible to animate the fade in and out like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gVp7m/ but with your format?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

## jsFiddle - would something like this do?

If it needs more explination just let me know. I broke it into spaces to make it easier to read.

> CSS

```
body {background: rgba(0,0,0,1); margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgba(255,255,255,1); }
#Splash { position: fixed; top:0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; background: black; }
.wrapper {width:100%; height:100%; max-height: 100%; background: rgba(0,0,0,1); }
.intro1 {  }
.intro1 div { position: absolute; bottom: .5em; opacity: 0; }
.intro1 .name1 { left: .5em; }
.intro1 .name2 { right: .5em; }
.intro2 {  }
.intro2 div { position: absolute; opacity: 0; }
.intro2 .prof1 { left: 40%; }
.intro2 .prof2 { right: 40%; }
```

> Script

```
$(".intro1 div").animate({ opacity: 1 }, 2000);

$(".intro1 .name1").animate({
    left: "40%",
    top: ".5em"
}, 3000);
$(".intro1 .name2").animate({
    left: "60%",
    top: ".5em"
}, 3000);

$(".intro1 div").animate({ opacity: 0 }, 2000, function(e) {
    $(".intro2 div").animate({ opacity: 1 }, 2000);

    $(".intro2 .prof1").animate({
        left: ".5em",
        bottom: ".5em"
    }, 3000);
    $(".intro2 .prof2").animate({
        right: ".5em",
        bottom: ".5em"
    }, 3000);

    $(".intro2 div").animate({ opacity: 0 }, 2000, function(e) {
        $("#Splash div").hide();
        $("#Splash").fadeOut(3000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Haha, that is awesome! Thank you for your feedback, I will definitely look in to it some more.

Comment: @p4trk Added, "Do It Again" button for fun, :P